# Using diff to show both contents of new files and that new empty files are created

Tags: diff

After executing these 4 commands, directory "a" has file "1" with contents "test" and file "2" which is empty, and directory "b" is empty.

```
$ mkdir a
$ mkdir b
$ echo test > a/1
$ touch a/2
```

We can run

```
$ diff -r a b
Only in a: 1
Only in a: 2
```

Which isn't helpful for a patch.  Or, we can run

```
$ diff -rN a b
diff -rN a/1 b/1
1d0
< test
```

Which is great for file "1" because we see its contents, but now file "2" has disappeared.  This is because the `-N` flag means "treat absent files as empty", so I presume diff can't see the difference between the empty file "a/2" and the (pretend, since really empty) empty file "b/2".

Is there a way to make diff show us, in one execution, that a new empty file has been created, and the contents of a new non-empty file -- in a format that patch can use?

Or, would this require a new option to diff?

Comment: This question is clearly _not_ a duplicate of the referenced question. The user explicitly tried what was proposed as a solution in the referenced question and that did not solve his problem.

Comment: @Durrant and others - can you guys un-mark this as a duplicate?  Dubu is correct.  In fact, that post is where I read about the -N option.  But, using that is where I ran into the unwanted side effect of -N making "b" basically disappear in the diff, where not using -N would at least tell you "b" only exists in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the plain `diff` from GNU diffutils cannot handle changes such as `b` (remove empty files).  [makepatch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/makepatch/) might be useful for that situation.  It's available as [a package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/makepatch) on Debian/Ubuntu.